# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory in Django

Tags: python, django, sendmail, email-attachments, filenotfoundexception

I'm working on a Django project where I need to send a file to the client via my system by email. But when I put the file name in the attach_file() field, I get the error of not finding the file.
This is my code:

```
def email_sender(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        subject = 'welcome to GFG world'
        email_from = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
        recipient_list = ["example@gmail.com", ]

        to = 'example@gmail.com'
        text_content = 'This is an important message.'
        msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, text_content, email_from, [to])
        msg.attach_file('file.file')
        msg.send()
```

And this is my exception:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'file.file'
[08/Dec/2021 11:52:52] "GET /email/send/ HTTP/1.1" 500 83111
```

This is my setting.py:

```
...
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]
...
```

This is my project structure:

```
src
   \_emailsender
               \_ urls.py
               \_ views.py
               \_ setting.py
   \_ static
            \_ file.file
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `attach_file` method does not have search functionality, if using a relative path you need to be aware of the CWD of the the Django process which is probably not the static dir. You could try `static/file.file` but I suggest going with an absolute path.

```
from emailsender.settings import BASE_DIR
...
msg.attach_file(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static', 'file.file'))
msg.send()
```